# TFS Advice on maintaining a project and adding classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

We have multiple developers working on the same project.  We all keep adding additional classes to be referenced based on a database entry.  So we have a couple hundred classes now.  What I am seeing is if I create CLASSA and someone else does a Get Latest, CLASSA does not get added to that person's solution explorer (project) but it DOES get transferred to that person's coding folder.  They have to manually go in and add/existing to their project.

Is this the correct/expected functionality of TFS?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like CLASSA gets added to TFS and becomes part of changeset but .csproj (or .vbproj) changes are not becoming part of changeset. How are you adding new file CLASSA to the project? If you use Solution Explorer to add new items, VS will automatically pend changes both proj file AND the new class file.

Comment: Every newly added or deleted files in the solution updates the `.csproj` file of the respective project. This file is very important as it holds all the entries of what all files the project has.. So you need to make sure to check in this file as well..

Comment: Wouldn't they have to be checking in the `.csproj` also? Otherwise the next person that tries to add a class to the project wouldn't be able to because it would still be checked out.

Comment: Did you check in the changes for the project file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you don’t check in or push changes of project file to source control. It will add Compile section in ItemGroup of your project file, then the VS can recognize that class file is included in the project.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App_Start\BundleConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\FilterConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\RouteConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\AccountController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\HomeController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\ManageController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Global.asax.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Models\AccountViewModels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\IdentityModels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\ManageViewModels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\UserInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Startup.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

For that scenario, I recommend that let a user (e.g. developer manager) to add necessary classes to project when new tables added to database instead of multiple developer to add classes that they want, otherwise they need to deal with conflicts when check in or get latest files.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the correct/expected functionality of TFS?

Depends on how you're adding CLASSA to the project.

It seems like CLASSA gets added to TFS and becomes part of changeset but .csproj (or .vbproj) changes are not becoming part of changeset. How are you adding new file CLASSA to the project? If you use Solution Explorer to add new items (Right click on project | Add | (New Item... or Class...), VS will automatically pend changes both proj file AND the new class file. During check-in, both will be committed together.